# command line utility to connect to wireless network

Tags: windows, windows-xp, wifi, windows-command-prompt

Can any one tell me a command line utility to connect to a wireless network in Windows XP.
I cannot use netsh wlan as this is not supported in XP.
Is there any open source command line utility tool . We need this for our automation .

Regards,
Mithun

Comment: +1 for the question as this was an annoying problem we solved in our imaging/deployment process.

Answer (score 0):

To automate joining wireless in any OS, admins should look into WPA(2) Enterprise. This allows deployment of wireless network via policies and otherwise. It can use certificates on each machine to authenticate, and be transparent to the user.

Answer (score -1):

Sure, you can do this with a utility called DevCon.
Per the web site:
"The DevCon utility is a command-line utility that acts as an alternative to Device Manager. Using DevCon, you can enable, disable, restart, update, remove, and query individual devices or groups of devices. DevCon also provides information that is relevant to the driver developer and is not available in Device Manager.

You can use DevCon with Microsoft Windows 2000, Windows XP, and Windows Server 2003. You cannot use DevCon with Windows 95, Windows 98, or Windows Millennium Edition."

File available from:
http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/1/f/11f7dd10-272d-4cd2-896f-9ce67f3e0240/devcon.exe

You can test to see if it works, you can type 'devcon help'.

You'll have to do some reading on the site, but it's fairly easy to figure things out.
I would post more links but I'm a new user, and i don't have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: `devcon` allows you to enable or disable devices but it does not allow you to configure or join wireless networks.

Comment: The OP did not ask for a command line tool to enable to disable devices. The OP asked for a command line tool that connects the wireless card to a wireless network.